# Vue Node.js/express app error cannot set property render of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js

I have a Vue CLI3 app setup, it is working perfectly fine when i run the app using `npm run serve`, however, after running `npm run build` to prepare the app for deployment, when running the app using Express it gives me an error in the console saying `cannot set property render of undefined`.. here is my server.js file setting in the root of my app

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const serveStatic = require('serve-static');

let app = express();
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/dist"));


const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join( __dirname, './dist/index.html')); //path to index.html
  });

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port)
});
```

this is a screenshot of my package.json
[image]

these are the error logs i am getting in the console
[image]
any help ?!

Comment: would be nice to see the code where error actually happens

Comment: not quite sure what do u mean when error actually happens, the error is logged to the console in the browser when i run `node server.js` so i expect the app to be rendered to the browser in the given port, what actually happens instead is, like i said, `cannot set property render of undefined

Comment: in the error there will be filenames and linenumbers so you can see exactly at which point the error occured

Comment: check the post again, i added a screenshot of the errors, thanks in advance

Comment: Well your error happens on the browser part of executon so somewhere in your client javascript code; the code you sent here is from your server side application

Comment: I am very confused now, i mean like i mentioned in the post, when i run the app in the development mode using `npm run serve` the app gets rendered prefectly fine in the browser, the issue only happens when using server.js :S

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join( __dirname, './index.html')); //path to index.html
});
```

your new code be like

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const serveStatic = require('serve-static');

let app = express();
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/dist"));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
  app.get('*', function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join( __dirname, './index.html')); //path to index.html
    });


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port)
});
```

Comment: but the index.html is now in my `/dist` not in my `/src` folder, again this is a CLI3 setup, but i get ur point anyway, so u mean if i added `this code to my server.js` with specifying the path to the index.html it will be fixed ?

Comment: @ Swilam Muhammad  i use express on the basis of that i am suggesting you.You can give a try or we will delete the ans

Comment: you don't need to say "or we will delete the answer" i said nothing wrong man, and  i tried your answer with the path to the index.html in my dist dolder and it didn't work.